# how can i use a for loop so my character can double jump?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to code a platforming game as right now all my character model can do is either jump infinitely or doesn't jump at all. I want to use a for loop so my character can jump one when grounded and once more when he is in the air but I cant figure out how to make it stop after double jumping once and resetting when the character hits the floor again. please help!!

```
public class SimplePlatformController : MonoBehaviour
{

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool facingRight = true;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool jump = false;
    public float moveForce = 365f;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 1000f;
    public Transform groundCheck;




    private bool grounded = false;
    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();                        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) 
       {
            grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
            {
                i = 0;  
                jump = true;

            }

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !grounded)
            {
                jump = true;
                i = i + 1;
            }

        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(h));

        if (h * rb2d.velocity.x < maxSpeed)
            rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.right * h * moveForce);

        if (Mathf.Abs(rb2d.velocity.x) > maxSpeed)
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(rb2d.velocity.x) * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);

        if (h > 0 && !facingRight)
            Flip();
        else if (h < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip();

        if (jump)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
            jump = false;
        }
    }


    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

}
```

Comment: [For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) --Adding for reference

Comment: Can't you add an event handler to the Input? Then when the jump button is hit you can do your logic inside the event handler

Comment: @RyanWilson im unsure how to set up an event handler sorry. (kinda new to all this coding stuff)

Comment: @SamAustin can you explain why you want to use a for loop for this?

Comment: I suppouse this function is called inside Update, right?

Comment: @SamAustin (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

Comment: Declare a property
private int jumps = 2;

and then

if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && (grounded || jumps > 0))
{
     jumps--;
     // your jump code

Comment: @RyanWilson that is for UI Elements, not for Input based off of keyboard/controller.

Comment: @SamAustin Please provide your actual code, what you have provided will not run inside Unity.

Comment: @Eddge ive added my full code for the player controller

Comment: @SamAustin first, do your input detection inside of update, otherwise you will have issues with the FixUpdate loop on movement(such as movement appearing delay).  Second you do not need a for loop for this, update runs every frame.

Comment: I know two word comments don't help, but...  Boolean Flags?  e.g.  IsInAir, HasAlreadyAirJumped, IsOnGround...  you'd be able to use those then you work out your logic.

Comment: @Eddge sorry but I don't know what my input detection is that your referring too :/

Comment: @Eddge It shows how to use an event handler.

Comment: @RyanWilson yes, it shows how to use the EventHandler that is attached to UI Buttons, feel free to post one that shows how to add one to the Input.

Comment: @Edgge I posted that to give the OP an example of using event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop is inappropriate for this, because you only want to advance the counter if you jump. and you need to leave the loop when it's time for the frame to end. You could in theory make it happen with a `while` loop in a `Coroutine` but that is unnecessarily complicated.

A better alternative is to just keep a counter as a class field and update it appropriately, according to the double jump state.

Also, since the if statement is being reached on every frame, you have to check if you have any more air jumps before you double jump.

If you want to be able to double-jump after you simply walk off a platform, you'll want to set the jump counter to `0` anytime `grounded` is set to be `true`.

Combining all of these suggestions might look like this:

```
public class SimplePlatformController : MonoBehaviour
{

    // ...

    private int airJumpCount = 0; // Add this counter

    // ...

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(
                transform.position, groundCheck.position, 
                1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

        if (grounded) airJumpCount = 0; // reset the counter when grounded

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        {
            jump = true;  
        }

        // Only enter the air jump block if we still have more air jumps
        if ( Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !grounded && airJumpCount < 1) 
        {
            airJumpCount++;
            jump = true;  
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```